# Calling MATLAB Superclass of a superclass constructor

Tags: matlab, oop, inheritance, constructor

I have the following problem.  I have three classes: A, B, and C.  A is the base class, B inherits A, and C inherits B.

Each has a constructor that takes in alot of arguments.  However, the constructor for B does a few steps that I don't want in C that I can't undo unless I add more interface code, which would break encapsulation for a few variables.  Namely, I'd give the user of my class the ability to change a few variables that I don't want them to.

As a result, I thought that I'd be clever and try to call the constructor of A from C.  However MATLAB doesn't like this.  See code below.

```
classdef C < B
  % properties go here
  % ...
  methods(Access = public)
    function obj = C(arguments)
      obj = obj@A(A's arguments);  % MATLAB doesn't like this
      % ...
    end
  end
```

So, how can I (or can I not), call the constructor to A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the constructor for B does a few steps that I don't want in C

In that case, your C is not an B. If the constructor from B is not executed in the construction process of C, then C cannot be a valid object of class B. However, the inheritance relationship implies this.

As such, the inheritance C < B is wrong. You should inherit C from A.

If you really want to, I'd try to implement a (mostly empty) protected constructor in B that is then called from C. Not entirely sure that works in Matlab though.

Comment: wow, how did I miss that!  Thanks!  Of course, B "is a" A, but C "is not a" B.  Thanks for the catch!